# Is there an alphabetical character check in prolog?

Tags: character-encoding, prolog, character, swi-prolog

Greetings,

Is there was test or a predicate I can use in prolog to verify that a certain given character is alphabetical? Right now, what I'm doing is:

List of unallawed characters: \n -> 10, space -> 32, !->33, .->46, ,->44, :->58, ;->59%
% 63->? , 45 -> -,  34->", 39->                                                         %

```
\+member(Ch,[10, 32, 33, 34, 39, 44, 45, 46, 58, 59, 63 ]), %Checking for line return           (\n),     space, punctuations
```

Those are only a few of the characters I need to check for. having a test such as letter(Ch). would save me a great deal of time, and above all be a  way more defensive approach.

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

is_alpha/1

There are also other predicates such as is_lower/1 etc.

Answer (score 2):

In SWI-Prolog, this is done with [char_type/2](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=char_type/2) such as

```
% X is either a single-character atom or a character code
alphabetical(X) :- char_type(X, alpha).
```

SWI-Prolog also offers the [ctypes](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc/swi/library/ctypes.pl) library which provides `is_alpha`, etc.

```
:- use_module(library(ctypes)).
alphabetical(X) :- is_alpha(X).
```

Comment: Nit: When using character codes, rather [`code_type/2`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=code_type/2) should be used. SWI does not check for it and accepts both, though.